# Solution of a problem of size

Tags: logic, category-theory

I know that the set of all groups does not exist. It's the same in the case of the topological spaces, and the sets themselves. My question is: How the Tarki's axiom solve this problem?

I can't see how the universes of Grothendieck gives sense to the staments "set of all groups", and the same.

Comment: These axioms don't imply that the set of all groups exists. They do imply that for any given set $X$, we can find a set $C$ such that $X \in C$ and such that $C$ is closed under the constructions implied by the axioms of ZF set theory (unordered pairs, subsets, unions, power sets, relational images). So the set of all groups in $C$ is (for most purposes) as good as the class of all groups in ZF set theory.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't, it gets **around** it.

There is (in $\mathsf{ZF}$ at least) no "set of all groups," and since that's a *theorem* of $\mathsf{ZF}$ adding additional axioms isn't going to change that. However, we can look at the particular ways in which we're tempted to *use* a hypothetical "set of all groups" in practice, and ask whether there might be some actually-consistent-with-$\mathsf{ZF}$ (+etc.) proxy for that.

Now $\mathsf{ZF}$ has a very nice framework for developing such ideas - namely, the **cumulative hierarchy**. For each (limit, for niceness) ordinal $\alpha$ we can talk about the set of all groups of [set-theoretic rank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_universe) *(this is unrelated to the group-theoretic notion of rank)* $<\alpha$; this will be a genuine set, and in fact an element of $V_{\alpha+1}$. The idea now is that if $V_\alpha$ is "nice enough," this approximation to the naive thing we want will actually do all the specific things we want it to.

This is where Tarski comes in. Things are very nice indeed if $V_\alpha$ is a Tarski universe (= if $\alpha$ is a strongly inaccessible cardinal), and we wind up with the following basic theme:

> Suppose there is a proper class of strongly inaccessible ordinals $\alpha$. Then for any particular application we care about, we can find a set $\mathfrak{S}$ which is "sufficiently like" the class of all groups for our purposes - specifically, we'll take $\mathfrak{S}$ to be the set of groups in $V_\alpha$ for $\alpha$ a "sufficiently large" strongly inaccessible cardinal.

Comment: when you say *rank of a group*, are you referring to this concept https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_of_a_group?

Comment: @JohnMars No, I was referring to "rank" in the sense of [set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_universe). I'll clarify that.

Comment: Do you mean by 'sufficiently like' the definition-properties of the Grothendieck universes?

Comment: @JohnMars I'm not exactly sure what you mean, but it's just a heuristic (hence "theme"): the idea is that for any particular argument, you'll almost certainly just need a "sufficiently closed" set of groups, and the set of groups in $V_\alpha$ for a large enough inaccessible $\alpha$ will almost certainly do the job.

Comment: @JohnMars I think this will all become much clearer if you look at a specific example of an argument which uses universes.

Comment: Could you recommend me some references to read more about this? I'm reading the first volumen of Basic Category Theory by Francis Borcuex